# GDB -tui option

Tags: debugging, gdb, tui

I've seen people using gdb with -tui option and they get pretty good source code in top, split window and below that gdb debugger, same thing I tried to do that in Ubuntu 15.04 but it is not showing the source code of the program in top window rather it shows "no source available". Can anybody suggest me how can I get that effect? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you compiled the program with `-g`? (with debug symbols)

Comment: Thanx, you got the mistake, I missed -ggdb3.

Comment: can you tell me what is difference between -g and -ggdb3

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2009-02/msg00130.html for example